# A question about derivation of Fourier coefficients

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-series

As the textbook said:

Trigonometrical polynomials
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{v=1}^{n}(a_v\cos{vx}+b_v\sin{vx}) \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
The Fourier coefficients can be expressed simply by the following formulas:
$$
a_u=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos{ux}\,dx, {\ } b_u=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin{ux}\,dx. \tag{2}
$$
The proof follows if we multiply Eq. (1) by $\cos{ux}$ or $\sin{ux}$ and then integrate.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

My derivation:

$$
\begin{align}
\cos{ux}\,f(x) & = \frac{a_0}{2} \cos{ux} + \sum_{v=1}^{n}(a_v\cos{vx} \cos{ux} +b_v\sin{vx} \cos{ux}) \\
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos{ux}\,f(x)\,dx & = \frac{a_0}{2} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos{ux}\,dx \\
& \phantom{={}} + \sum_{v=1}^{n}\left(a_v \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos{vx} \cos{ux}\,dx +b_v \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin{vx} \cos{ux}\,dx\right)
\end{align}
$$
According to the orthogonality relations of the trigonometric functions, we get:

$$
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos{ux}\,dx =0, \\
& \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos{vx} \cos{ux}\,dx = \pi, \quad \text{if } u=v, \\
& \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin{vx} \cos{ux}\,dx =0.
\end{align}
$$
So, if $u=v$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos{ux}\,f(x)\,dx & =  \sum_{v=1}^{n} a_v \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos{vx} \cos{ux}\,dx =  \sum_{v=1}^{n} a_v \pi  
\end{align}
$$
I can’t get the Eq. (2), where’s the mistake? Thanks.

my question's unique part is, derivate this equation:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{v=1}^{n} a_v \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos{vx} \cos{ux}\,dx = a_v \pi  
\end{align}
$$
and it was solved by @Ak19.

Comment: Except at $v=u$, the sum is $0$ . So on the RHS you'll simply have $a_v\pi=a_u\pi$

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment,

$$\sum_{v=1}^na_v\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos vx \cos ux \ dx = a_1\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos x \cos ux \ dx+a_v\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos 2x \cos ux \ dx+\cdots +\\a_u\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos ux \cos ux \ dx+\cdots+ a_n\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos nx \cos ux \ dx\\=a_1\cdot0 +a_2\cdot0+\cdots a_u\cdot\pi+\cdots a_n\cdot0 = a_u\pi$$

So, 

$$a_u\pi = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(ux)dx \implies a_u =\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(ux)dx$$

Comment: @Ak19 I got it, thank you very much.

Comment: @Shogun no, my question is just for my “cancel-out” step, it’s specific.

Answer (score -1):

To generalize, the derivation is easier if you prove it for a complex variable; i.e: $$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx:n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

where the Fourier expansion is of the form $$f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_n e^{inx}$$.

for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$; simply consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and you can use this method for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

**Proof:**

Fix $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Consider the integral:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-imx}dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_n e^{inx}e^{-imx}dx$$
$$=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}c_n e^{inx}e^{-imx}dx.$$

Clearly if there is any residual exponential term, integrating that term from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ will yield $0$, regardless of the magnitude of the coefficient of that term, as any exponential term refers simply to a rotation, which will be the same at $-\pi$ and $\pi$. We have:
$$=\cdots+0+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}c_n dx + 0 + \cdots$$
$$=2\pi c_n,$$

divide by $2\pi$ to find $c_n$.

This proof comes with a nice visualization with epicycles: see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6sGWTCMz2k).

There's no mistake in your proof; you just need the last 'canceling-out' step.

Comment: Thank you very much.